# Show that for all integers : b) If  | 58, then +7 and ^2+9 are coprime.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Part a) stated : If  is an integer such that |+7 and |2+9, then |58. The next part (part b) is what i need help with. I thought I'd state this here for context.

Working out:

In order to see if a and b are coprime integers, we must ensure according to
Bezout’s Lemma that the following equation has integer solutions.

+=1

Now let =5+3 and =7+4. Now we get:

(+7)+(^2+9)=1

Now we can apply Euclid’s Algorithm:

(^2+9) = n (+7)+(-7+9)

(+7)=(-7+9)+(8-2)

(-7+9)=-1(8-2)+(n+7)

(8-2)=8(+7)-58

(Stuck over here)

We now just go back:

1= …

Having obtained 2 solutions (,)= , we can prove that the above numbers are coprime.

Is my way so far correct? What do I do next? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is hard to read.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good turorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: The statement in the title is false. $1|58$, but $8$ and $10$ are not coprime.

Comment: Did you possibly mean $58\,|\,n$ instead of the other way round?